# How to maintain selected row of XtraGrid control

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, xtragrid

I'm developing an application of the xtragridview control in that application when i'll double click on row from the xtragridview that time one popup form opens . then the focus  of the parent window changes & focus is assigned to the another form which is popup . and that time my selected row changes it's state & it focus/select the default 1st row from the xtrgridview.
but i want to maintain the focused/selected row as it is if user changes the focus from one form to another pop up form.

Is there any solution on this solution? what properties of xtragridview control should i've to set for this problem?

thanxs.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, the approach you are using does not require you to write an additional code.  The XtraGrid does not reset its FocusedRow if you open a form by doubleclicking a grid row.  So, I would suggest that you determine the cause of this behavior.  This can be done by using the following approach:

1)  handle the GridView's FocusedRowChanged event and set a breakpoint in it.

2) reproduce the issue and check which code forces the gridView to focus the first row.

This should give an idea on why this happens.

Also, I would suggest that you review the [How to create the PopupForm for editing rows in the GridView and automatically create editors based on the column editors.](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/CodeCentral/ViewExample.aspx?exampleId=E1293) example where the required functionality is implemented.

I think I know the cause of this problem.  It appears because you are changing the DataView's RowFilter property.  I think you want your editors to point to the clicked record.  The best solution is to do not filter the DataView but to assign the BindingContext as it is done in the example above. Here is the code from it:

```
public EditForm(Point location, GridColumnCollection columns, object dataSource, BindingContext context)
            : this() {
            StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
            Location = location;
            BindingContext = context;  // <<<<<<
            allowTrackValueChanges = false;
            this.dataSource = dataSource;
...
}
```

Comment: you are absolutely  wright . i'm using dataview's filterrow property for filtering or serching perticular record from the dataview.       thanks for your help.  can you suggest some documentation about what you are takimg?

Comment: What should i use instead of Row filter for selecting a particular record from the dataview?

Comment: @priyanka,  Generally, you should use the approach from the article you've posted.  In this case, there is no need to filter the DataView.  The editor bound to the same data source will show data from the active record and this record will correspond to the active record in the "browse" form.

Comment: You are wright but i want to update that record in my table then how should i do this by using what you are talking?

Comment: @priyanka, take a look at the code I've posted.  The DataSource object is passed to the EditForm.  So, there should not be a problem to change the table's row if the EditForm's OK button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Mehod 1:

In the double click event handler just mention

```
return;
```

after all processes (Opening of another form etc.) are done.

**After understanding your question better, I suggest to try method 2** I hope it surely works.

Method 2:

First record the current selected index before it opens another form or dialog ..

```
int index = datagridview.SelectedRows[0].Index;  //or xdatagrid.SelectedRows[0].Index;**
```

Then after completion of form opening or other procedure add the following line

```
datagridview.Rows[index].Selected = true; //or xdatagrid.Rows[index].Selected = true;**
```

**N.B.: I have never used xdatagrid, but suggesting the solutions depending on my datagridview experience.

Comment: i used gridview's double click event & in this case it not provides Handled property. Is there any other solution?

Comment: @priyanka: Add `return;` statement instead of `e.Handled = true;`

See the code above for clarity

Comment: It is not working. because i used dataview as a datasource to the xtragrid view & when user double clicks on the particular row that time i changed the filter row property of the dataview. & used same dataview in my whole application . And that's why i'm unable to maintain the selected row's focus .   Is there any another idea?     thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

I use

```
 GridView view = (GridView) sender;
 Point pt = view.GridControl.PointToClient(Control.MousePosition);
 var info = DoRowDoubleClick(view, pt);
```

when DoRowDoubleClick is:

```
 private static GridHitInfo DoRowDoubleClick(GridView view, Point pt) {

            GridHitInfo info = view.CalcHitInfo(pt);

            if (info.InRow || info.InRowCell){

                string colCaption = info.Column == null ? "N/A" : info.Column.GetCaption();

                MessageBox.Show(string.Format("DoubleClick on row: {0}, column: {1}.", info.RowHandle, colCaption));
                return info;
            }
            return null;
        }
```